# Replacing entire column with fixed range in formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a bit of a strange problem that I'm trying to solve.

I have a large macro-enabled Excel file that takes around 3 minutes to calculate all the formulas in it. I did not create this file but I'm trying to see if there is a way to expedite the calculation.

I have tried all the usual tricks of disabling screen updating, changing calculation to Manual but I also noticed that almost all of the formulas in this file reference entire columns instead of fixed ranges so `$A:A` instead of `A1:A1000` or similar.

There are different formulas on different tabs so I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically replace such instances with a fixed start and end cells. I know I can use `Find/Replace` but I don't want to have to do it for every single formula if there is a better way to do it using VBA.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to read each cell on a worksheet and replace entire columns with fixed ranges. For example:

Old formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX('426'!$CC:$CC,MATCH($J14&"Space",'426'!$CN:$CN&'426'!$CB:$CB,0)),"")`

New formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX('426'!$CC1:$CC5000,MATCH($J14&"Space",'426'!$CN1:$CN5000&'426'!$CB1:$CB5000,0)),"")`

Thank you!

Comment: Referencing entire columns should not be an issue. Excel is smart enough to limit it to the actual data. At least I could not measure any difference in runtime. Are you sure that changing your formula this way boosts performace? • There is no way to do this automatically besides using find/replace.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I believe it does as I tried manually changing it on one of the worksheets and it did calculate faster, albeit only by a few seconds but if I change it on all the worksheets (there are about 20), it should result in significant performance boost.

Comment: I doubt that but you can try. As I said there is no automation for that.

Comment: Of course you can use VBA to modify the formula, but the effort would so high that you might want to implement those formula in VBA and do all kinds of optimization.   One experience to share, though.  I once have a workbook with tones of formula that runs forever. And I finally figure out that it is somehow related to MSOutlook. Once it is closed, the speed boosted up by 4 times.  I don't know why and my calculation has NOTHING to do with Outlook. So, this is just an observation that some other applications could mess up the speed.  May worth to take a look.